# Is the space of E-spectral functions of Lp(G) Banach?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, abelian-groups, harmonic-analysis

By the space of $E$-spectral functions of $L^p(G)$ where $G$ is an infinite compact abelian group, $E \subseteq \Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is the dual group of $G$, and $1<p<\infty$, I mean the set

$L_E^p(G) = \{f \in L^p(G) : \widehat{f}(\gamma) = 0, \forall \gamma \notin E\}$

**Is this set a Banach subspace of $L^p(G)$?**

Since the Fourier transform is linear on $L^1(G)$ and $L^p(G) \subseteq L^1(G)$ since $G$ is compact, therefore $L_E^p(G)$ is a subspace of $L^p(G)$. I have read what seem to be implicit references to it also being a complete space, but I can't find an actual reference for it.

Comment: In your definition of $L^p_E(G)$, do you mean $\widehat{f}(\gamma) = 0$ for all $\gamma \notin E$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan that is indeed what I meant, sorry about that, thanks for pointing that typo out. it is fixed in the question now

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

I claim that indeed $L_E^p(G)$ is a Banach subspace of $L^p(G)$.

First, note that trivially $0 \in L_E^p(G)$, and that since the Fourier transform is linear, therefore $L_E^p(G)$ is clearly closed under addition and scalar multiplication and hence is a linear subspace of $L^p(G)$.

To show that $L_E^p(G)$ is moreover a complete subspace of $L^p(G)$, since $L^p(G)$ is complete itself it is therefore sufficient to show that $L_{E}^{p}\left(G\right)$ is a closed subset of $L^{p}\left(G\right)$. Let $f_{n}\in L_{E}^{p}\left(G\right)$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow f\in L^{p}\left(G\right)$. It is sufficient to show that $\widehat{f}\equiv0$ on $\Gamma-E$. Since $G$ is compact, therefore $L^{p}\left(G\right)\subseteq L^{1}\left(G\right)$. Also since $1<p$ and $f_{n}-f\in L^{p}\left(G\right)$ and that the Haar measure $\lambda$ on $G$ is normalized, therefore

$\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert _{1}\leq\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert _{p}$

Hence $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}\left(G\right)$ too. Since the Fourier transform as a mapping $L^{1}\left(G\right)\rightarrow L^{\infty}\left(\Gamma\right)$ has operator norm less than or equal to $1$, therefore it is bounded and hence

$\left\Vert \widehat{f_{n}}-\widehat{f}\right\Vert _{\infty}=\left\Vert \widehat{f_{n}-f}\right\Vert _{\infty}\leq1\cdot\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert _{1}$

Consequently $\widehat{f_{n}}\rightarrow\widehat{f}$ in $L^{\infty}\left(\Gamma\right)$. Since for any $\gamma\in\Gamma$

${\displaystyle \left\Vert \widehat{f_{n}}-\widehat{f}\right\Vert _{\infty}=\sup_{\tau\in\Gamma}\left|\widehat{f_{n}}\left(\tau\right)-\widehat{f}\left(\tau\right)\right|\geq\left|\widehat{f_{n}}\left(\gamma\right)-\widehat{f}\left(\gamma\right)\right|}$

therefore $\widehat{f_{n}}\rightarrow\widehat{f}$ pointwise. Let $\gamma\in\Gamma-E$. Now $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$,

$\left|\widehat{f}\left(\gamma\right)\right|=\left|\widehat{f_{n}}\left(\gamma\right)-\widehat{f}\left(\gamma\right)\right|<\varepsilon$

since $f_{n}\in L_{E}^{p}\left(G\right)$. This implies $\widehat{f}\left(\gamma\right)=0$.